# Monitoring new records on Oracle database using WSO2 Business Activity Monitor

Tags: wso2, business-rules, wso2-bam

Is it possible to monitor new transactions being loaded or inserted into the  oracle database table using  WSO2 Business Activity Monitor and WSO2 Business rules. If yes how should I configure  WSO2 Business Activity Monitor to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to directly monitor Oracle DB table and conclude the transactions in the BAM. However, if these transactions are happening via wso2 esb / wso2 AM / WSO2 BRS, you can monitor these activities via WSO2 BAM